# unicode to string conversion swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, unicode

```
Es ist eines der Wahrzeichen 
Bambergs: das Alte Rathaus, auch Insel- oder Br&uuml;ckenrathaus 
genannt, das die fr&uuml;here Herrschaftsgrenze zwischen der 
b&uuml;rgerlichen Inselstadt und der
```

I want to convert all unicode to string from above string.

Comment: `&uuml;` is a so-called "HTML entity"

Answer (score 0):

We have the following method in our project:

```
- (NSString *)convertHTMLToUnicode {
    NSArray *theHTMLEntities = @[@"&amp;", @"&Auml;", /* more stuff */];
    NSArray *theUnicodeEntities = @[@"&", @"Ä", /* more stuff */];

    NSDictionary *theHTMLSource = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:theUnicodeEntities forKeys:theHTMLEntities];
    NSMutableString *theText = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self];
    for (NSString *theHtml in theHTMLEntities) {
        [theText replaceOccurrencesOfString:theHtml
                             withString:[theHTMLSource valueForKey:theHtml]
                                options:NSLiteralSearch
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, theText.length)];
    }
    return theText;
}
```

Comment: ok let me try this